# Error: factory runner does not support sending transactions DEPLOYMENT

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Hi im tyring to deploy my contract bug following error

```
Deploying TaskContract...
Error: factory runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.2)
    at makeError (/Users/daniel/Code/solidity/task-app-hardhat/blockchain/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:677:21)
    at assert (/Users/daniel/Code/solidity/task-app-hardhat/blockchain/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:694:25)
    at ContractFactory.deploy (/Users/daniel/Code/solidity/task-app-hardhat/blockchain/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/factory.ts:107:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at main (/Users/daniel/Code/solidity/task-app-hardhat/blockchain/scripts/deploy.js:9:24) {
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'sendTransaction'
}
```

My contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract TaskContract {
    event AddTask(address recipient, uint taskId);
    event DeleteTask(uint taskId, bool isDeleted);

    struct Task {
        uint id;
        string taskText;
        bool isDeleted;
    }

    Task[] tasks;
    mapping(uint256 => address) taskToOwner;

    function addTask(string memory taskText, bool isDeleted) external {
        uint taskId = tasks.length;
        tasks.push(Task(taskId, taskText, isDeleted));
        taskToOwner[taskId] = msg.sender;
        emit AddTask(msg.sender, taskId);
    }

    function getMyTasks() external view returns (Task[] memory) {
        Task[] memory temporary = new Task[](tasks.length);
        uint counter = 0;

        for (uint i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            if (taskToOwner[i] == msg.sender && tasks[i].isDeleted == false) {
                temporary[counter] = tasks[i];
            }
        }

        Task[] memory result = new Task[](counter);

        for (uint i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            result[i] = temporary[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    function deleteTask(uint taskId, bool isDeleted) external {
        if (taskToOwner[taskId] == msg.sender) {
            tasks[taskId].isDeleted = isDeleted;
            emit DeleteTask(taskId, isDeleted);
        }
    }
}
```

and my deployment file:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  // Compile the contract
  const TaskContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("TaskContract");

  // Deploy the contract
  console.log("Deploying TaskContract...");
  const taskContract = await TaskContract.deploy();

  // Wait for the contract to be mined
  await taskContract.deployed();

  console.log("TaskContract deployed to:", taskContract.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

my config file:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();

const { INFURA_API_KEY, SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.15",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: `https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      account: [`${SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `hardhat-deploy` plugin is a good approach.

And about your issue, i think your .env private key is incorrect. check that.

Answer (score 0):

In `hardhat.config.js`, you should use `accounts` instead of `account`

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();

const { INFURA_API_KEY, SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.15",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: `https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [`${SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
  },
};
```